Immersive lab - ASP.NET Core Web API: Business Logic Flaws
Update the RedeemCode method to successfully update the database when the code is used.
public void RedeemCode(Codes code, int userId)
{
    using (var tx = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        UpdateUserBalance(code, userId);

        tx.Commit();
    }
}

private void UpdateUserBalance(Codes code, int userId)
{
    var amount = code.Amount;
    _dbConnection.Execute(@$"
                UPDATE {nameof(User)}
                SET {nameof(User.Balance)} = {nameof(User.Balance)} + @{nameof(amount)}
                WHERE {nameof(User.Id)} = @{nameof(userId)}", new { userId, amount });
}


Yes ?!? What is your question - what problem / challenge are you facing?

what is issue iare you facing?

Consumecode(code); is missing after UpdateUserBalance(code, userId); line.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
